# how can I redirect traffic to Linux

Tags: linux, redirection

How can I redirect my router traffic to my Linux operating system, I have tried Google but nothing came up.
I have tried a lot of iptables commands and Google

Comment: Are you saying you want your Linux system to act as a HTTP proxy?

Comment: Disregard my previous comment. I guess the simpler thing to do is to eliminate your router altogether and let your Linux machine act as a Wi-Fi access point and have all your network devices connect through it. You can [find](https://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/04/21/use-your-laptop-as-a-wifi-router-under-linux/) [tutorials](https://prahladyeri.wordpress.com/2013/05/26/how-to-turn-your-linux-machine-into-a-wifi-access-point/) on how to do this online.